# Least Squares Regularization by feature transformation

Tags: regression, machine-learning, self-study, feature-engineering

Assume we have a data set of n points in d dimensions, represented by feature matrix X ∈ $R^{n×d}$ and corresponding output vector y ∈ $R^n$
. Let T = $τI_d$, where $τ$ ≥ 0, and $Id$ is the $d×d$ identity
matrix. We define a new feature matrix $X'$ ∈ $R^{(n+d)×d}$
and output vector $y'$ ∈ $R^{n+d}$ as follows:

$X'$= $[\frac{X}{T}]$,
$Y'$=$[\frac{Y}{0}]$.

What type of regularization do the d added data points impose and what is the difference from the objective for the original data
set ($X$, $y$)?

It seems to look like a ridge regression with the role of $τ I_d$ being to make the Gram matrix $X'^T$$X'$ invertible by ensuring each eigenvalue is at least $τ$ but I can't really prove it mathematically. Can anybody help me with this? How does it change the objective function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is in fact ridge regression, as you say. To show it, I think you only have to replace $X'$ and $Y'$ for $X$ and $Y$ in the usual expression for ordinary least squares, $\hat\beta = (X^tX)^{-1}X^tY$. If you perform the matrix products by blocks you end up with: $$\hat\beta_{\tau} = (X^tX + \tau^2I)^{-1}(X^tY + \tau I 0) =  (X^tX + \tau^2I)^{-1}X^tY$$
i.e. ridge regression.

Comment: As for the objective function, I think it is the sum of squares penalized by $\tau\beta^t\beta$, so it shrinks the betas towards zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! Can you however explain me how do you go from $(X'^t X')^{-1}X'^{t}y'$  to $(X^{t}X+τ^{2}I)^{−1}(X^{t}Y+τI0)$ ?

Comment: Yes, for instance $X'^tX' =  (X | T)^t (\frac{X}{T}) = X^tX + T^tT = X^tX + \tau^2I$. Same with other products, you simply multiply block by block.